# Is it possible to compute overlaps between rectangles in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, overlap

TensorFlow newbie here.

I am developing a neural network which outputs the (x,y) coordinates of two oposite corners of N rectangles.

I was thinking about implementing a cost funtion that takes into account the overlaps between the predicted rectangles, since they are not meant to be overlapped at all, but a simple cost function with the MSE results in some overlapping.

I was wondering if it is possible and since it might be complex if Tensorflow can compute the gradient of these computations to minimize the cost function.

Note that i want to check the overlap between rectangle 1 and rectangles 2 to N, and between rectangle 2 and rectangles 3 to N and so on.

Is this possible or am I better off just post processing the data and separate the overlapping rectangles?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a modified version of the Intersection over Union (IoU) criteria. It is mostly used in image detection to detect the position of objects in images and allows to discard boxes about which the net is most unsure.

In your case, you want to maximize the union (you reach the max when the two rectangles are not overlapping) and minimize the intersection (theoretically, you want it to be 0). As a results, the IoU must be minimized and in the best case it is equal to 0.

To implement this in TF you can do:

```
cost = 0
for first in range(num_rectangles):
    for second in range(first, num_rectangles)
        cost = cost + compute_IoU(rect[first], rect[second])

cost = cost / num_rectangles
```

There are several implementation of the IoU. One si provided by [TF itself](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/mean_iou).

Comment: So can I just sum the cost to the previous cost function I had? Doesn't it have to be done with TF operations for it to be possible to compute the gradients?

Comment: Yes, you can just add the costs. If the cost you already have is a tensor, then tensorflow will convert the cost coming from IoU into a tensor and will map the '+' to `tf.add()`. All the gradient's stuff will be automatically managed by TF.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using the fact that the minimum and maximum operators support broadcasting.

Reshape this output `coords` to have shape `(B, N, 2, 2)`, where  `B` is the batch size and `N` the number of rectangles. The areas of the overlap can be computed as

```
c1 = coords[:, None]
c2 = coords[:, :, None]
areas = tf.reduce_prod(tf.maximum(
  tf.minimum(c1[..., 1], c2[..., 1]) - tf.maximum(c1[..., 0], c2[..., 0]), 0.), axis=-1)
```

From there you can compute a cost, not forgetting to take care of the diagonal elements (corresponding to the area of the rectangles). For example to simply sum the areas,

```
cost = tf.reduce_sum(areas) - tf.reduce_sum(tf.trace(areas))
```

True, you are doing some extra computations -- the diagonal elements, and also overlaps are computed twice -- but I believe this should be insignificant compared to the remainder of your net and probably faster that something based on a loop.

This cost is of course differentiable automatically by tensorflow.